# Can I remove perpendicular ceiling joists in porch

Tags: structural

I have porch attached to the exterior wall of the house roof is pitched away from the house:

[image: similar construction to mine]

I am in the process of gutting it and want a vaulted ceiling. There are ceiling joists running perpendicular to the rafters (i.e. from side to side, parallel with wall of house). Because the roof is not pitched in that direction, i assume these do not form any part of the structure and can be safely removed. Is this a correct assumption?